# The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Hi I have problem in my code and it seems it has something to do with the instances but I declare already a instance in the controller and it seems it is not working.

I got this error:

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[PEMCOLoan.DAL.Entities.spModels.spGetLedger]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'PEMCOLoan.Web.Models.Ledger'.

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult getEmployeeLedger(spGetLedger ledger)
    {
        var firstDay = _Context.LoanPayments.Min(min => min.DateOfPayment);
        var lastDay = _Context.LoanPayments.Max(max => max.DateOfPayment);

        //Set Test data

        //Set Parameter
        var StartDate = new SqlParameter("StartDate", firstDay);
        var EndDate = new SqlParameter("EndDate", lastDay);
        var EmpID = new SqlParameter("EmployeeID", ledger.EmployeeID);
        var LoanTypeID = new SqlParameter("LoanType", ledger.LoanTypeID);

        Ledger newLedger = new Ledger();

        newLedger.enumledger = _Context.Set<spGetLedger>().FromSql("EXECUTE spGetLedger @EmployeeID, @LoanType, @StartDate, @EndDate", EmpID, LoanTypeID, StartDate, EndDate).AsNoTracking();
        //var empLedger = _Context.getLedger
        return View(newLedger.enumledger);
    }
```

**Views**

```html
@model PEMCOLoan.Web.Models.Ledger

@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Ledger";
}

<h2>View @Model.ledger.FullName's Ledger</h2>
<h3>Loan Name: @Model.ledger.LoanName</h3>
<h3>Total Loan Amount: @Model.ledger.TotalLoanAmount</h3>

@if (Model.enumledger.Any())
{
    <table class="table table-responsive">
        <tr>
            <th>Date Paid</th>
            <th>Principal Amount</th>
            <th>Interest</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach(var item in Model.enumledger)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PaymentDate)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalLoanAmount)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Interest)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Total)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
<h3>Balance: @Model.ledger.Balance</h3>
```

Answer (score 2):

[AsNoTracking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352(v=vs.103).aspx) returns IQueryable.  Change it to .AsNoTracking().ToList() to force the retrieval at that point.

Comment: Hi! I have an error in my Wrapper in my Model class and it seems it has something to do with ViewDataDictionary the error shows this:
`InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[PEMCOLoan.DAL.Entities.spM‌​odels.spGetLedger]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'PEMCOLoan.Web.Models.Ledger'.``

Comment: change View(newLedger.enumledger);  to View(newLedger);

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `.ToList()` :

```
Ledger newLedger = new Ledger();

newLedger.enumledger = _Context.Set<spGetLedger>().FromSql("EXECUTE spGetLedger @EmployeeID, @LoanType, @StartDate, @EndDate", EmpID, LoanTypeID, StartDate, EndDate).AsNoTracking().ToList();

return View(newLedger.enumledger);
```

Comment: Hi, I already changed it right now. to `AsNoTracking().ToList()` and it seems that another error appears again.

`InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[PEMCOLoan.DAL.Entities.spModels.spGetLedger]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'PEMCOLoan.Web.Models.Ledger'.`

Comment: in the view change the model to  @model List<PEMCOLoan.Web.Models.Ledger>

Comment: Hi @Mostafa, As you can see I set the Dictionary on the model itself. Do you have any idea whats wrong with this? Thanks!